# DateTime value issue

Tags: datetime

I am setting datetime value like this-

```
visitation.Date_of_Visit__c = system.now();
```

Even though current time is 4:30 AM it is showing 4 AM in Date_of_Visit__c 
But createdDate time is 4:30 AM which is correct. 
Can anybody please advise/help on this issue.

Comment: Is `Date_of_Visit__c` having datetime datatype

Comment: yes it's of type datetime.

Comment: When you are showing 4:30 or 4 you mean on user interface and not on apex debug logs. What is timezone and locale of user ?

Comment: Yes in UI. If I can see createdDate as 4:30 AM then  Date_of_Visit__c should also be 4:30 AM irrespective of Locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I was using this field later in my code to set external id -

```
visitation.External_Id__c = visitation.Contact__c + String.valueOf(Date.valueof(visitation.Date_of_Visit__c));
```

Though I am converting Date_of_Visit__c value from DateTime to Date I am not storing it back to Date_of_Visit__c field. This is something weird I have observed.

I had to make slight changes in my code as shown below -

```
visitation.Date_of_Visit__c = DateTime.newInstance( dt.getTime());
DateTime extDate = DateTime.newInstance( dt.getTime());
visitation.External_Id__c = visitation.Contact__c + String.valueOf(Date.valueof(extDate));
```

Instead of using Date_of_Visit__c, have created one datatime variable and used that while setting external id field.